# Visual Studio 2015 project keeps crashing

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having an issue with a project I purchased which uses VS 2015.

For some reason I got it to run only once, powered down and never was able to run again. No computer updates were done in between.

I gave all source code and database files to a friend who is very familiar with VS, and he got it to run immediately. He probably also has other VS and SQL version on his computer, so there may be trace elements from those installs making it run - you know how MS stuff works!

This is making me think something different about our computer systems is the issue. I am still waiting to hear back.

I'm getting errors mentioning connection errors or file not found, but the html page describing everything is not clear.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

---

but then error states

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.

This is not true since I'm able to connect using  SQL Server Management Studio.

I've installed everything the seller mentioned to me:

- Visual Studio 2015 Community edition
- SQL Server Express --- (I installed 2012)
- IIS web server
- Extensions to install into Visual Studio

  - Nuget Package Manager
  - Nunit 2 Test Adapter

Comment: " I got **it** to run only once" - What is **it**... is it Visual Studio, or the application you built using Visual Studio?

Comment: Post your code. Remember to include the SQL connection string.

Comment: <add name="ProspectData" connectionString="Data Source=.\NWSQLEXPRESS ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=ProspectData8-Staging;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\NWSQLEXPRESS ;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Now, whatever they were trying to connect which I see in the Server Explorer, that is always red X's out when I start the project.

Comment: I have altered this to get it to connect but this should not be the issue. The code should be doing everything, correct? As I mentioned I can open the db in Management Studio 2012 using SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: I got 'it' the project/program to start in VS and open in the browser. It's a web based gaming site.

Comment: Why is your application connecting as `sa`? That is never a good idea. Create a Login and User(s) with permissions for what the application needs to do, and only what it needs to do. An Application should never have `sysadmin` privileges on your SQL Server.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: 'sa' was the default the seller was using when this site was up and running. He worked for Google, so he would have set things up properly I'm certain.

Comment: When the browser windows opens (only after I stop the run), the error shown states: Cannot open database "database-name" requested by the login. The login failed.  Yes I can indeed connect to this database with same credentials using SSMS. I'm thinking (since I'm on a Win 7 home edition running 2012 sql express) the error is suggesting I really need another OS or another SQL installed. Obviously this error is not specific enough!

Comment: Turns out the production database would never run the site. I then took an older staging db, added what ever data I needed - and got the site to run. BUT this will only run on my desktop WIN7 IIS7.5  machine, not on a new laptop WIN10, IIS10 and more importantly my remote server WIN2012 Server IIS 8.5.  This should all work cross platform but doesn't. It's not the web.config file, it seems to be how IIS is set up. I'm using the same paths to the root and virtual directory. PLEASE HELP